# ValueError Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have some issue in Django 2.0.2 ..

in model.py file I have :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256 , unique=True)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class GameScore(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} - {} {}'.format(self.first_team.name,self.first_team_score,
                                      self.second_team_score,self.second_team.name)
    first_team = models.ForeignKey\
        (Team,related_name='first_team',null=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    second_team = models.ForeignKey\
        (Team,related_name='second_team',null=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_team_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    second_team_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    GameDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and when I try to add GameScore the error come !
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'RM'

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to run when you get that error.

Comment: I try from admin page in Django 2.0.2

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the error ? And also, how do you register your model with the admin ? any `admin.ModelAdmin` ?

Comment: please paste `admin.py` file by editing your question, not as a file in some 3rd party hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By examining your Database, there is something populated wrong. In `GameScore` instance with `id=3` having `first_team_id='RM'` , but it should be some `integer` value denoting the `Team` instance.
**Results**

```
In [13]: GameScore.objects.get(id=3).__dict__
Out[13]: 
{'GameDate': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 12, 40, 3, 255264, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7f99acc309b0>,
 'first_team_id': 'RM',
 'first_team_score': 0,
 'id': 3,
 'second_team_id': 'Barca',
 'second_team_score': 0}
```

**How To Solve This Issue ?**
While examining the DB I found that many of the `first_team_id` and `second_team_id` are `str` type. As far as I knew they never became a `str` type unless someone manually change their values.
**Solution-1**
Delete all data and regenerate the table and **do not assign `string` values to the `second_team_id` or `first_team_id`**
**Solution 2**
Manually change the values of `second_team_id` and `first_team_id` to some integer denoting their corresponding `FK` relation